# Error Python Subprocess call copying file. No file, Fails, but returns 1. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.6

```
import subprocess
import os

#files
src_file = '/../copy_me_test.txt'
destination_file = 'paste_here.txt'

#make copy of file
shell_command = 'cp "%s" "%s"' % (src_file, destination_file)
successful = subprocess.call(shell_command, shell = True)
print(successful)
```

So I am copying a file from one directory to another. When I run the subprocess.call() method it returns a 1. Except that nothing happens and I get the following message on my terminal.

```
cp: /Users/my_name/Desktop/python/copy_files/copy_me_test.txt: No such file or directory
1
```

What's going on here? Shouldn't this return a 0 since it failed to make a copy of the file. I made a work around already but I would like to know if anyone knows why this is happening? Any information or links would be appreciated.

Comment: Side-note: Don't use shell programs when you don't need them. Take a look at [`shutil.copyfile` and friends](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) to do this directly from within Python, with no fragile/hard to error check/non-portable external program usage.

Comment: I'll do that. I'm new to python so I appreciate the advice. I don't really understand what you meant by" no fragile/hard to error check/non-portable external program usage."

Comment: Instead of catching exceptions in Python when you call a executable as a subprocess you have to capture the return code and compare it to constant, known error codes in an if-else ladder. This makes it hard to use. The error codes may also be different depending on the platform your script runs on, potentially making it non-portable. The return codes may also change in a newer version of the executable, making them fragile.

Comment: Well that actually makes a lot of sense. You have given me a lot to think about. Thank you for explaining that. I'll try to keep that in mind next time I am doing these kinds of tasks in my programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation here https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html it will return 1 when it fails, also check that there is a warning if you use the attribute shell=True

Comment: Thank you so much. That checks out. While the documentation was a little confusing I ran my program a couple of times and the results were consistent with what you said. I was following a tutorial. I must have misunderstood it. Thanks again.

Comment: @EmmanuelCodev no problem! don't forget to accept one answer! with the check box https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 3):

Return 0 is success. Not 0 is failure. Return code can be a 32 bit integer from 0 to [4294967295](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4,294,967,295). Look at [Exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX) based on operating system.

Sometimes a negative return code may be set or received as Python 3 docs confirm.

> Popen.returncode
>
> The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.
>
> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only).

Exit Python with `exit(-1)` results in `4294967295` on Windows so Python uses a unsigned 32 bit return code.

Comment: Yes. I realize now that I misunderstood the meaning of the return values. Thank you for explaining it to me in more detail. I see now why 0 is used as a marker for success.